# Comparing two columns in Excel with exclusion

Tags: excel, excel-2007, worksheet-function

I want to compare values in two columns in Excel as depicted in the image below :- 
[image]

Using the formula, I want to put the values in the "Values of A which don't exist in B" and "Values of B which don't exist in A". Any help is appreciated.

I have shared the same excel sheet [here](http://www.filedropper.com/comparevalues).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The following will work - for each, add the formula in row 2 and then drag down

**Values of A that do not exist in B**

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH($A$2:$A$20,$B$2:$B$17,0)),A2,"")
```

Result = x, y, z, i, j ,k, l, u

*NB: Your example spreadsheet is incorrect as u is in Col A but not Col B but you do not list it in your result set in Col C*

**Values of B that do not exist in A**

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH($B$2:$B$17,$A$2:$A$20,0)),B2,"")
```

Result = q, r, e, f, g

Comment: What does $ signify? When you write the in the the first cell the $ does not get prefixed with it. I had to put that manually.

Comment: The $ makes the ranges absolute (i.e. A2:A20 and B2:B17). What this means is that when you drag down the formula the references remain A2:A20 and B2:B17. If you didn't do this the ranges would increment i.e. A2:A20, A3:A21, A4:A22. Try the formula without the $ signs and you will see what I mean...

Comment: Can you explain why absolute range is required for the value parameter in the match function? This works for me:-=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A2,$B$2:$B$17,0)),A2,"")

Comment: I know this is bit dated but your function helped but with Excel 2016, I did the direct cell to column compare without the $ and dragged the formula down for the rest. Otherwise it gave me some false mismatches =IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A1,B:B,0)),A1,"")

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this with Advance Filter
Assuming Data in Col A and B
In Cell C2 write =SUMPRODUCT(--($B$2:$B$17=A2))=0
Select Data A1:A12
Click on Advanced Filter, Choose copy to another location
List Range = $A$1:$A$22
Criteria Range = $C$1:$C$2 (Note C1 to be blank)
In Copy to Range choose  E1, Say OK
This will give you Values of A that don't exist in B

In Cell D2 Write =SUMPRODUCT(--($A$2:$A$22=B2))=0

Select Data B1:B17
Click on Advanced Filter, Choose copy to another location
List Range = $A$1:$A$22
Criteria Range = $D$1:$D$2 (Note D1 to be blank)
In Copy to Range choose  F1, Say OK
This will give you Values of B that dont exist in A

You can automate this Via a single line of Code

Sub Get_Data1()

[List1].AdvancedFilter 2, [Crt1], [Dest1], True

End Sub

Sub Get_Data2()

[List2].AdvancedFilter 2, [Crt2], [Dest2], True

End Sub