# Mark items in column B that are not in A (in Excel)

Tags: excel

Assume the following Excel worksheet:

```
   A    B
1 foo  foo
2 bar  foobar
3 baz  bar
4      baz
5      bam
```

In reality, columns `A` and `B` contain thousands of rows (with column `B` being longer than `A` as is the case here). I need to check column `B` against `A`. Items that appear in column `B` but not in `A`, need to be marked (color red, make bold, add star, this is not important).

In this example the items that should be marked are: `foobar` and `bam` as the do appear in `B` but not in `A`. My question is: with what formula can I accomplish this?

Comment: See [comparing two columns with exclusion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5768129/comparing-two-columns-in-excel-with-exclusion/5769395#5769395)

Comment: This can be achieved using conditional formatting with help of a formula. The formatting part cant be done only using formula. Are you familiar with condition formatting?

Comment: I guess this question will be closed, because it isn't related to programming as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the example of the formula to achieve this using conditional formatting

`=ISERROR(VLOOKUP(B1,$A$1:$A$3,1,FALSE))`

Put the source range (for your case) instead of `A1:A3` above.
Make sure that the conditional formatting applies to the data range (of the column B), say B1:B2000.

Answer (score 3):

You can use COUNTIF like this in C1 copied down

`=COUNTIF(A:A,B1)>0`

that will give TRUE if the B1 value is in column A or FALSE otherwise

alternatively you can use the same formula in conditional formatting to colour the relevant rows